# In Regular Expressions, can I retain a value from the header into each row?

Tags: regex

For my Source string, I am running the windows command "NET GROUP  /domain >> textfile.txt" fifteen times in succession for each of fifteen Active Directory groups, appending all of that into a file called textfile.txt.

So I get the following:

```
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain do3o2s.com.

Group name     AD_GROUP_TESTERS
Comment        blabla Tester

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
person88                   person24                   
The command completed successfully.

The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain do3o2s.com.

Group name     AD_GROUP_ADMIN
Comment        blabla

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
person1                   person2                   person3                   
person4                   person5                   person6                   
person7                   person8
```

The regex I'm trying is

```
(?:Group name     (?'ADGroup'[^\n]*)\n)|(?:^Members\n\n-*\n)(?:(?'U1'[A-Za-z0-9 ]{25})?(?'U2'[A-Za-z0-9 ]{25})?(?'U3'[A-Za-z0-9 ]{25})?\n)*
```

which works great in .NET C# Flavor to recognize all of the group names and all of the names in the group, but when listed back out only seems to list one line of people per group.

Is there a way to get all the people?

Yes, I'm playing around with Regex101.

Comment: why are you using a regex when windows has apis that you can use to query that information

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't do this with regex. You need a parser, or run a few regexes multiple times.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED, Oh I see.  I should have used AWK instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I am populating an Excel Power Query with the output, so I did not consider using the API.